# Create Round Button with Border IN UWP Windows 10 C#

Tags: c#, xaml, button, win-universal-app

I am trying to create a round button, with a White Border and a Transparent Background (as the old AppBarButtons in Windows 8.1) in UWP Windows 10.

I have found several samples like these:

https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2015/05/23/windows-10-universal-windows-platform-custom-button/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cda7a526-5e99-4d4a-a73c-0be4ce77f961/uwpwindows10-how-to-make-button-with-round-edges?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required

But the problem is with the Border.
When I setting the BorderBrush to a certain color, it turns out the Border is for Button's "Rectangle".

Is there a way I can create a Round border for a button?

Comment: You can vote for out of the box support for rounded buttons here: [UserVoice: Add CornerRadius property to Button](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/20323243-add-cornerradius-property-to-button)

Comment: Seems as though it becomes available in 1809 Oct 2018 build

Comment: @peterincumbria if you have the 1809 kit installed you can use it in earlier targetted versions by using this as the drop-in-replacement property for a `Button`: `Windows10version1809:CornerRadius="90,90,90,90"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are few ways to achieve this, one by using a style can look like this - remove *BorderBrush* from *ContentPresenter* and add an *Ellipse* with that brush. Sample in XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CircleButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                       <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderCircle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderCircle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderCircle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderCircle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="BorderCircle" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="text" Width="50" Height="50" BorderBrush="Blue" Style="{StaticResource CircleButtonStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

I've also made some changes in *VisualStates* so that it doesn't look weird once clicked/disabled.

Comment: This throws a xaml exception: "Cannot resolve TargetName BorderCircle"

Comment: It should be `<Ellipse Name="BorderCircle" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="2"/>`

Comment: @TekGiant Right, I've somehow lost this during copying. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Background="Transparent">
        <StackPanel>
            <Border CornerRadius="10" 
                    Background="Transparent" 
                    BorderBrush="White" 
                    BorderThickness="3">
                <TextBlock Text="MyButton" 
                           Margin="10" 
                           Foreground="White"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The only con about this is that the size of the circle is different if the number has less than two digits...

Comment: @Cabuxa.Mapache you can make the button bigger

Comment: FI, you can also set a different value for every corner.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if the OP is still interested in rounded corner buttons, but for sake of completeness I think it may be helpful for other users to point out, as the user peterincumbria said, that for the lastest build of Windows 10 (1809) there is a new property in the class `Control`: `CornerRadius`. So now the following code is enough:

```
<Button Content="DEMO"
        Background="Transparent"                    
        BorderThickness="1.0"
        BorderBrush="White"
        CornerRadius="10"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Put this inside a `Grid` and we have a rounded corner button in the middle of the `Page`.

Answer (score 4):

With version `1809` and later (even if you're targeting an earlier version like me below) you can just do this for an example of a round button:

```
<Button
    Content="Stuff"
    Windows10version1809:CornerRadius="90,90,90,90"
    Height="64"
    Width="64">
</Button>
```

and voila!

[image]

Make sure to add this at the top of your XAML with the other `xmlns` stuff.

```xml
xmlns:Windows10version1809="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, 7)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another sample

```
<Style x:Key="ProfileButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AppBarHeaderBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="9"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Grid  Margin="0,0,0,0" >
                                <Ellipse x:Name="ButtonShape" Height="40" Width="40" Fill="#FFFDFCFC" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    Stroke="{StaticResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <!--This glyph is the Contact (head and shoulders silhouette) glyph. -->
                                <TextBlock x:Name="Icon" Text="&#xE13D;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonContent" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="12"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="{Binding Source={StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}, Path=Color}" 
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonShape" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#eeeeee" 
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonEllipse" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Result

[image]

Or Create fully customizable cornerradius

//Create a template control xaml design

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:UWP.Library2.Controls">
<Style  TargetType="local:CustomRoundedButton">
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10,10,10,10"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomRoundedButton">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <!--<Rectangle RadiusX="60" RadiusY="60" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />-->
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" ></Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter  CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
                                       AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                       BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                       ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                       ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                                       Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                       HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                       Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                       VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

//Template control.cs

```
public sealed class CustomRoundedButton : Button
{
    private Grid _rootGrid = null;
    public CustomRoundedButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomRoundedButton);
    }
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _rootGrid = GetTemplateChild("RootGrid") as Grid;
    }
    public CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(CustomRoundedButton), new PropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(10,10,10,10)));

}
```

//Register to or merge dictionary from /Themes/Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///UWP.Library2/Controls/CustomRoundedButton/CustomRoundedButton.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Answer (score -1):

The approach I just used was to simply add CornerRadius to the "RootGrid" grid in the Button template.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="RoundedButton">
    ...
    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" CornerRadius="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"> 
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: Nothing new here.