# How to make a round edges Button Style base on default style

Tags: c#, templates, uwp

Good Day,

I want to know how can I make a button looks like this using the default style from this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx

[image]

I found articles that add this line after the content presenter but it is very rounded:

```
<Ellipse Name="BorderCircle" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="2"/>
```

Thanks,
NicoTing

Comment: Have you looked into - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241037/create-round-button-with-border-in-uwp-windows-10-c-sharp

Comment: yes , thats what I said that adding Ellipse , but it is too rounded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you round edges in the button and you can use UWPCommunityToolkit for Shadow.

**Without UWPCommunityToolkit**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}" Content="Sign In" Background="#0086f1" Foreground="White" Height="35" Width="150"/>
```

**Style**

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="DefaultButtonStyle" x:Key="DefaultButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <!--Changes-->
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#FFF9F7F7" CornerRadius="5">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>                                        
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>                                       
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <!--Changes-->
                    <Grid x:Name="myGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="5">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
                                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" 
                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                      CornerRadius="5" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Result**

[image]

**With UWPCommunityToolkit**

> Xaml Reference

```
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
```

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
     <controls:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="8"
                               ShadowOpacity="0.7"
                               OffsetX="2"
                               OffsetY="2"
                               Color="Black"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}" Background="#0086f1" 
                Foreground="White" Content="Sign In"  Height="35" Width="150"/>
    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

**Result**

[image]

**Instruction For UWP Community Toolkit**

> 1. vs2017
> 2. Min SDK Windows 10.0.14393.x
> 3. Add nuget package "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
> 4. Link for getting start [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/getting-started)
> 5. [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/uwp-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq) UWP toolkit sample app for quick view what you can do with UWPCommunityToolkit or Codes

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but what I need is apply the radius from the default button style , code from the article I put in my question

Comment: Okay i will update the answer, and using uwp community toolkit is best way with shadow and effects

Comment: Okay , can you please add an example using that toolkit? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `Rectangle`

```
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid"> <!-- Delete Background -->
    ....
    <Rectangle RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: it is not working , I added it after the contentpresenter line from the default button style

Comment: Can you attach the output(when you use my solution) in your post?